# How to efficiently store and search keywords from a database?

Tags: python

Suppose,I have a file xyz.txt and keywords "apple" is associated with it.
Now,when user type any keyword(say apple) in searchbox,it should give him the files xyz.txt,abc.txt from database.

1. Should I use nosql or rdbms?
2. How to store it in database in dictionary form?
3. How to perform this search with flask,python?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in many ways. you can use python dict or rdms database also.

As you have not mentioned how keywords and related file names are added, I am assuming that you will add them manually

**method 1  - dict** : The dict goes like this. you can make a seperate file for it also.

```
my_dict = {
    "apple":{
        "xyz.txt",
        "abc.txt"
    },
    "banana":{
        "mno.txt",
        "pqr.txt"
    }
    
}
# searched term
keyword= request.args.get("keyword")
# you can get the files like this
files =  my_dict[f"{keyword}"] # will give the related files.
```

**method 2 - rdms database and [flask_sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/)**: make a database with this kind of schema

```
class My_table(db.model):

    sno = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key=True)
    keyword = db.Column(db.String(20))
    file = db.Column(db.String(20))

@app.route("/search")
def w_search():
    keyword = request.args.get('keyword')
    results = My_table.query.filter_by(keyword=keyword).all()
    for i in results:
        print(i.file)
    return results # use jinja for loop in template
```

A column keyword which store like `apple` and file store the name, `abc.txt` , as many files related to apple(particular keyword) that many rows will be there with `keyword="apple"` and their respective file.

if you want more complex search like `FULLTEXT`, and simple code then you can use , [flask-msearch](https://pypi.org/project/flask-msearch/).

Comment: I won't add them manually.When I upload some files,I have a checker,which extracts keywords automatically .Now I will store them in key-value pairs.

Comment: you can also use elasticsearch, which is a better search engine in rdbms. here's a [tutorial by miguel](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-full-text-search) for it. If my answer solved you problem, you can accept it as correct.